# Controlling File Permissions on a Windows File Share

Tags: macos, permission, file-sharing, smb

I'm using a Mac running Mountain Lion (10.8.3) with file sharing enabled to Windows users.

Whenever a Windows user copies a file into the share on the Mac (Windows file sharing), the permissions of the file are `600`, meaning that other users of the Mac cannot access the file.

Files copied from Mac clients (using AFP) have `644` permissions, which is perfect.

Is there a way to configure the permissions that are set by Apple's Windows file sharing?

Incidentally, I never had this problem previously with Snow-Leopard.

Comment: Same here for El Capitan. 

Also: even when using SMB on Mac clients (finder, cmd-K, `smb://servername.local/sharename`), `644` permissions are used.

Answer (score 3):

This is probably related to the "safe save" feature of SMB shares in OS X.

To allow group access enter in Terminal:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server AclsEnabled -bool YES
```

Source: [OS X Server: When saving files on SMB shares, the permissions might be changed so that only the owner can read or write](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203574)

Then modify/add an ACLs for the shared folder:

```
chmod +a "everyone allow list,search,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" <Shared_Folder>
```

and if additional permissions are necessary for a group

```
chmod +a "<group_name> allow list,search,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit,<additional_permissions>" <Shared_Folder>
```

and reboot - I don't know if it's sufficient to simply restart File Sharing in the Server.app.

The ACLs also have to be applied to all already existing subsequent items in the shared folder to make them accessible for network users.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I did restart File sharing via Server.app, and still get `600` permissions when creating files from windows...

Comment: @doekman Updated answer after some more testing.

Comment: I checked the ACLs, and OS X default adds them, and more, if you choose read/write-access (you also get add_file, add_subdirectory and delete_child). I also checked the directory I'm adding the file to with `ls -le` and I get the same rights there. The server is now in use; I hope to restart it end of day if I have time.

Comment: I wasn't in the position to reboot the server, and in 2 hours I'm off for holiday. It would be nice to suspend the bounty, but we'll see how it goes....